# Using sed or VIM to replace space with new line

Tags: linux, unix, sed, vi

I have the following data.

```
1455931_at Chrna3 1420468_at Asb17 1445520_at −−− 1436717_x_at Hbb−y 1431788_at Fabp12 1458975_at −−−
```

With `sed` or VIM editor how can I change it to

```
1455931_at Chrna3 
1420468_at Asb17 
1445520_at −−− 
1436717_x_at Hbb−y 
1431788_at Fabp12 
1458975_at −−−
```

So all the word that has `_at` will be the first of every line.
Every line consist of pairwise _at and gene terms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Vim, I would do this:

```
:%s/ /^M/g
:g/_at/j
```

Where the `^M` is typed by pressing control-V (control-Q on Windows) followed by the Enter/Return key.

This assumes single spaces between tokens; as @Floris suggests, you can use `s/ \+/^M/g` to turn multiple consecutive spaces into a single newline. Or you could use `s/\v\s+/^M/g` to do the same thing with any consecutive whitespace including tabs as well as literal space characters.

Comment: As long as there's just a single space this will work. Maybe want `%s/ \+/^M/g` for the first command? It takes care of extra whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Amazing but true:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.[^ ]* \)/\1 \2\
> /g' <<<"1455931_at Chrna3 1420468_at Asb17 1445520_at −−− 1436717_x_at Hbb−y 1431788_at Fabp12 1458975_at −−−"
1455931_at Chrna3 
1420468_at Asb17 
1445520_at −−− 
1436717_x_at Hbb−y 
1431788_at Fabp12 
1458975_at −−−
```

In other words, the `sed` string I used had a physical carriage return in it (the `>` was added by the console):

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.[^ ]* \)/\1 \2\
> /g'
```

You could experiment a bit with other expressions (right now I'm assuming balanced pairs, but if you specifically want to match the `at` at the end of the first string you could).

Comment: Is it possible to use that in VIM?
I tried this in VIM visual mode but failed
`:'<,'>!sed sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.[^ ]* \)/\1 \2\ ENTER` but failed before adding `/g'`

Comment: In bash or other POSIX shell, you can also take advantage of POSIX strings and type that as `$'...\\\n/g'`

Comment: @MarkReed - three backslashes for the newline? Can you explain? Please?

Comment: @Floris - `$'\\\n'` is transformed by the shell into the same sequence as in your answer: a backslash followed by a newline; `sed` can't tell the difference.  In a POSIX string `$'...'`,  `\\ ` becomes a literal backslash and `\n` becomes a newline, so putting them together you get `\\\n` for backslash + newline.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed: `s/ /\n/g; s/_at\n/_at /g`
There might be a more elegant solution but this one will do.

Comment: Looks elegant but in my version of `sed` (Mac OS) the `\n` is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

for your example,

```
sed -e 's/\(_at [0-9a-zA-Z−]*\) /\1\n/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(_at[[:blank:]]\{1,\}[^[:blank:]\{1,\}\)\([[:blank:]]\)/\1\
\2/g' YourFile
```

This allow any "space" as separator and in one or more occurence, no \n on last line. This take 1 "word" after any portion of string terminated by `_at`, not alternance of word (interpretation from my side).

This does not avoid 2 "_at" to be write on 2 separate lines (case there is a missing/empty word)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i,$(i+1)}' file
1455931_at Chrna3
1420468_at Asb17
1445520_at ...
1436717_x_at Hbb.y
1431788_at Fabp12
1458975_at ...
```

This prints two and two fields.

Another version:

```
awk '{printf $0 FS;getline;print}' RS=" " file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to find all 2-word pairs where the first word ends with "_at"

```
grep -oP '\S+_at\s+\S+' file
```

or, to put a newline after every 2nd word:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < file | paste -d " " - -
```